# AngularJS IE Error: SCRIPT 5009: 'JSON_XYZ' is undefined

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, internet-explorer-9

I am accessing a REST Service that returns a JSON back. The JSON response is of the format 
JQUERY_1234({ABC:[]}).
Using angularJS and IE9 as the browser, I get an error that says SCRIPT 5009: 'JQUERY_1234' is undefined. I am new to angular JS and would appreciate some guidance on where I am going wrong.
The same code works for another URL but fails on this one. Thanks for your help!

My controller code is:

```
var myNameSpace=angular.module('myApp',[]);
myNameSpace.controller('MyController',function MyController($scope,$http){
$http.jsonp('URL').success(function(data) {
$scope.artists = data;
})
.error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
alert("error:" + status);
return status;
});
    $scope.orderAlerts='Name';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The URL string that is used for the JSON needs to have the parameter callback="JSON_CALLBACK". It is a mandatory parameter for http.jsonp